# combine two Map String into JSON

Tags: java, json

Here is JSON String what I expected:

```
{
    "startDate": "2013-01-01",
    "columns": "mode , event",
    "endDate": "2013-02-01",
    "selection": {
        "selectionMatch": "123456789012",
        "selectionType": "smart"
    }
}
```

And Here is the JAVA codes, but I didn't make it successful:

```
public static String BuildJson() throws JSONException{

    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("startDate", "2013-01-01");
    map1.put("endDate", "2013-02-01");
    map1.put("columns", "mode , event");

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("selectionType", "smart");
    map2.put("selectionMatch", "123456789012");

    JSONArray ja2 = new JSONArray();
    ja2.put(map2);
    System.out.println(ja2.toString());

    map1.put("selection", ja2.toString());

    System.out.println();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    ja.put(map1);
    System.out.println(ja.toString());

    return null;
}
```

The challenge is how to combine the two map string that are not at the same level.
My code result is :

```
[{"startDate":"2013-01-01","columns":"mode , event","endDate":"2013-02-01","selection":"[{\"selectionMatch\":\"123456789012\",\"selectionType\":\"smart\"}]"}]
```

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that u want,

```
public static String BuildJson() throws JSONException
    {

        JSONObject map1 = new JSONObject();
        map1.put("startDate", "2013-01-01");
        map1.put("endDate", "2013-02-01");
        map1.put("columns", "mode , event");

        JSONObject map2 = new JSONObject();

        map2.put("selectionType", "smart");
        map2.put("selectionMatch", "123456789012");

        map1.put("selection",map2);

        System.out.println(map1.toString());

        return null;

    }
```

the output will be

```
{
   "startDate":"2013-01-01",
   "columns":"mode , event",
   "endDate":"2013-02-01",
   "selection":{
      "selectionMatch":"123456789012",
      "selectionType":"smart"
   }
}
```

Use JSONObject instead of Map, if u need JSONArray u can use that also.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, It spent me lots of time. I am not familiar with JSONObject, so now you give me exactly right direction, I am going to browse the api.

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(map1);
object.put('selection', map2);

System.out.println(object.toString());
```